# ¿Cómo poner el título de las entradas a la derecha en Blogger?

Tags: post, blogger

vi un tutorial de cómo presentar de otra forma los posts en el home de blogger, sólo que el título queda arriba de la imagen y no arriba del "summary", como debería quedar. Adjunto una imagen de cómo debería ser y cómo resulta.

Quiero mantener la imagen a la izquierda y con esas dimensiones, sólo que el título esté dentro de esa caja y arriba del sumario, como la primera imagen. Espero me explique y me puedan orientar, gracias.

Aquí el link del tutorial:
http://www.bloggerbuster.com/2011/03/easy-post-summaries-and-thumbnails-for.html

[image: Esto es como quiero que resulte]

[image: Este es el resultado]

Answer (score 0):

normalmente se usa `text-align: right`; eso debería de funcionar, te debería quedar algo así

```css
h3.post-title {
font: normal normal 22px Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif;
margin: .75em 0 0;
text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="post-title entry-title" itemprop="name">
<p>Texto a la derecha.</p>
</h3>
```